# Как сохранить порядок сущностей в списке?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, hql

Есть список сущностей "todo", нужно помимо того, что бы сохранить его в базе по id как то сохранить порядок, то есть если пользователь захотел задачу с id 20 выполнить вперед всех остальных, то она должна оказаться на самом верху, в не зависимости от того, какие у всех остальных задач id.

Как это сделать учитывая, что порядок одних и тех же задач в разных местах может быть разный, например в папке inbox один, а в папке today - уже другой порядок, хотя задачи одни и те же.

Как решить поставленную задачу?

Comment: Если порядок имеет значение, то должны существовать данные, его устанавливающие. Если таковых нет - их следует создать. Для обработки на уровне БД лучше иметь нумерацию, чем последовательность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте коллекцию `TreeSet` с помощью своего компаратора по приоритету или добавляйте в ту коллекцию, в которой Вы храните сейчас, с помощью компаратора по приоритету. Таким образом Вы добьетесь порядка в коллекции.

Если Вы используете `ORM-системы`, то они автоматически восстановят из базы данных коллекцию с правильным порядком.